# Get 1 row per ID, per policy number and dates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a member id with different policy numbers along with any effective and cancel dates. I cannot get rid of extra rows in the query where the policy number is the same but does not have a date in the coverage or cancel date field. I have looked around and have not found anything here that is close. I could have easily missed it by not looking for it the correct way.
Here is the code i am trying to use to isolate it out. I get back 3 rows and only need 2 of them. I need to be able to to tell if they changed policy numbers at any time now or in past.

Code:

```
    select pp.member_id
    , pp.id as people_id
    , po.id as policy_id
    , po.person_id
    , po.client_id
    , po.policy_number
    , po.cov_dt
    , po.cancl_dt
    from people pp 
     left join policies po
      on pp.id = po.person_id;
```

Tried this to isolate the result to single policy. It only of course returns 1 row with max dates for both under 1 policy number which is wrong.
Code:

```
    select pp.member_id
    , cte1.policy_number
    , cte1.person_id
    , cte1.max_eff_date
    , cte1.max_cancel_date
    from people pp 
     left join (select  p.person_id, p.client_id, p.policy_number
                , max(p.cov_dt) as max_eff_date
                , max(p.cancl_dt) as max_cancel_date
                from policies p
                /*where p.person_id =52545*/
               ) cte1 ON pp.id = cte1.person_id ;
```

Result from 1st code:

```
member_id people_id policy_id person_id client_id pol_nbr cov_dt cancl_dt 
29D993E95 52545     58482     52545     59        904871  null   1/21/16
29D993E95 52545     58487     52545     59        904871 1/21/16 3/16/17 
29D993E95 52545     224370    52545     34434     909055 4/3/17     null
```

Result from 2nd query: i shortened this up to get result set back to show

```
member_id people_id policy_number client_id cov_dt cancl_dt
29D993E95 52545     904871        52545     4/3/17  3/16/17
```

Thanks for your help.

I forgot to add the result set i am looking to get. Guess that is why i was down voted. I do indent just like they say to do for code blocks. But it never ever takes it.

Result should be:
member_id people_id policy_id person_id client_id pol_nbr cov_dt cancl_dt 
29D993E95 52545     58487     52545     59        904871 1/21/16 3/16/17
29D993E95 52545     224370    52545     34434     909055 4/3/17     null

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by doing the obvious. Cant believe this slipped my mind on how to do it. Basically I had to many fields in subquery. Reduced it to policy_number and date fields. Problem solved.

Code for subquery only:

```
     SELECT p.person_id, p.policy_number
        , MAX(p.coverage_effective_date) AS max_coverage_effective_date
        , MAX(p.coverage_cancel_date)    AS max_coverage_cancel_date
        FROM policies p     
     GROUP BY p.person_id, p.policy_number
```

This produces desired result in total query from original ask:
member_id people_id policy_id person_id client_id pol_nbr cov_dt cancl_dt 29D993E95 52545     58487     52545     59        904871  1/21/16 3/16/17 
29D993E95 52545     224370    52545     34434     909055  4/3/17 null